# Dart polymer - javascript web components

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

Anybody knows whether it's possible to use regular html 5/javascript web component(s) libraries in a Dart application? I think starting from now a lot of web component libraries in html 5/javascript will arise that will be of use for developing Dart applications. As long as there will be no Dart Polymer equivalents those components will not be usable and we are bound to web components written in Dart is it?

Simply including the polymer.min.js in a Dart application throws an error? Maybe it's not that simple ;-)

Thanks,

Daniel.

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2:** If you can't wait, try [this](http://dart-lang.github.io/widget.dart/) :-)

**Update:** Okay, now I understand. You have to wait, see [here](https://www.dartlang.org/polymer-dart/#polymer-parity). "Polymer base elements" and "Polymer UI elements" are assigned as "Not started". Everything in Dart is now in live developing, so I think, we all, have to wait until they have it complete. I'm now waiting for circa 4 libraries for Dart, which might be completed soon, and your Polymer UI elements are going to be finished within the next few weeks... I think, there can never be any port for JS libraries, until anybody rewrites it by hand in Dart. You can join the developer club and help them to rewrite Polymer UI elements faster ;-)

---

> "Simply including the polymer.min.js in a Dart application throws an
>   error?"
>
> Can you describe, what did you mean with this? I think you should
>   include Dart Polymer Library and not JavaScript Polymer (see
>   [here](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/polymer) or
>   [here](https://www.dartlang.org/polymer-dart/))...

Comment: I mean: the Dart web components (http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/polymer_ui_elements) do not seem to get on par with the html 5/javascript web components http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/#elements that could be usefull for developing a Dart (mobile) app.

So, it would be nice to also use web components developed in javascript/html 5 until the dart web components are usefull.

I can't seem to find any UI widget libraries to build an application or are there more? (like http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/rikulo, but then accorrding to web components standard).